# Dynamic log file path in mule

Tags: logging, dynamic, mule

I m trying to change log file path in mule dynamically  I have set the system property in an expression component but since log4j2.XML decodes the value at compile time itself it is not getting reflected I have even set monitor interval in log4j.XML but it is not working how to achieve dynamic file path?

Answer (score 0):

To make your log file name and path dynamically is to set the path in environment variable.
In the log4j2.xml, you can do something like the following :-

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${sys:CustomapPath}/${sys:CustomapplicationName}_WARN.log"
filePattern="${sys:CustomapPath}/test/${sys:CustomapplicationName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-WARN-%i.log">
```

and you set these variables in your `apps.properties`:-

```
CustomapplicationName=Common-logging-Util
CustomapPath=E:/backup/test/log
```

or if you want to make it more dynamic, you can pass these value from VM argument as `-DCustomapPath=E:/backup/test/log -DCustomapplicationName=Common-logging-Util`

and in Standalone server as `-M-DCustomapplicationName=Common-logging-Util  -M-DCustomapPath=E:/backup/test/log`

So, now when the application loads you will find the log files generated at the location you mentioned.
**But** once it's loaded you cannot change the log file path from there as it has already loaded the file location.

Answer (score 0):

If you want run-time changes to logging, you'll need to initialise a new Log4J logger in a Java class. Otherwise using default Mule logging functionality requires you restarting/re-initialising the Mule application.